# EntityFramework extend base model in different DLL

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I have a DLL with a base model using code first EF 4.3. 
What i want is to extend certain models in that dll with additional fields.

for example in BaseModel.DLL

```
namespace BaseModel
{
   public class Account
   {
       public Id { get;set;}
       public string Name {get;set;}
   }
}
```

in a referencing project i want to extend the Account model (and DB table):

```
public class Account : BaseModel.Account
{
    public string SomeAdditionalInfo { get;set;}
}
```

I want to end up with a table Account with fields

```
Id
Name
SomeAdditionalInfo
```

This way i can keep reusing the BaseModel (and logic) in several similar projects.
I guess i can't use partial classes because we're speaking different DLL's. 
Maybe inheritance? I tried several ways but i keep getting conflicts about having 2 models with the same name.

Any hints? tips? solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use inheritance though Table per Hierarchy.
You can create base class AccountBase and child class Account:AccountBase:

```
public class AccountBase
{
   public Id { get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class Account : AccountBase
{
    public string SomeAdditionalInfo { get;set;}
}
```

It generates Table AccountBase that will contains columns Id, Name, SomeAdditionalInfo
There will be also column Discriminator that will contains instance of what class contains in this row.

Comment: Won't i get in trouble with foreign keys? In the base model it would want to use AccountBaseId and in the other model AccountId?

Comment: I recommend you use in base model property Id (as primary key) and this property will be inherited in child classes.

Comment: In class that has foreign key to this, you can set name of foreignkey column by fluent interface